# Selenium Nose TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nose

I have written some automated tests in Python Selenium Webdriver. I was reading up on Selenose (http://shiningpanda.com/introducing-selenose.html) as I want to try and use this for my test cases to run using the same instance of 1 web browser rather than opening a new browser for each test case.

I am getting the error when i run my Test Suite:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Full Error trace is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 121, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.3\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py", line 41, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "C:\Webdriver\Selenose\ClearCore\TestSuite\suite2.py", line 98, in <module>
    mySuit=suite()
  File "C:\Webdriver\Selenose\ClearCore\TestSuite\suite2.py", line 84, in suite
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestCases.AdministrationPage_TestCase.AdministrationPage_TestCase))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 312, in makeSuite
    return _makeLoader(prefix, sortUsing, suiteClass).loadTestsFromTestCase(testCaseClass)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 56, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I have nose.cfg in the TestCases folder, it's configuration is:

```
[nosetests]
with-xunit = true
with-selenium-driver = true
selenium-driver = sample

[selenium-driver:sample]
webdriver = ie
```

My TestSuite is (it is in a folder called TestSuite:

```
import sys
import unittest
from HTMLTestRunner2 import HTMLTestRunner
from Utilities.HelperMethods import get_datetime_now
import os
import unittest
import TestCases.AdministrationPage_TestCase
import TestCases.DataMapsPage_TestCase
import TestCases.DataObjectsPage_TestCase
# Some more imports ...

class Test_Suite(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_main(self):


def suite():
    """
        Gather all the tests from this module in a test suite.
    """
    test_suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestCases.AdministrationPage_TestCase.AdministrationPage_TestCase))
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestCases.DataMapsPage_TestCase.DatamapsPage_TestCase))
    test_suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestCases.DataObjectsPage_TestCase.DataObjectsPage_TestCase))
    # --- some more test cases
    return test_suite

mySuit=suite()

# output to a file
test_result_dir = os.path.join(r"C:\\Webdriver\\ClearCore\\TestReport\\") # Test report goes here

# open the report file
outfile = file(test_result_dir + "\TestReport_" + get_datetime_now() + ".html", "wb")

# configure HTMLTestRunner options
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,
                                       title='Test Report',
                                       description='Selenium - LA Demo create a basic project automated test')

# run the suite using HTMLTestRunner
runner.run(mySuit)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #unittest.main()
    HTMLTestRunner.main()
```

My AdministrationPage Test Case snippet is (It is in a folder called TestCases):

```
import nose
from selenose.cases import SeleniumTestCase
# some more imports...

class AdministrationPage_TestCase(SeleniumTestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver.get(Globals.URL_riaz_pc)
        self.login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(120)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_add_Project(self):
        print "*** test_add_project ***"
        project_name = Globals.project_name + get_datetime_now()
        print "project_name_value = " + project_name
        write_project_Name_toFile2(project_name)
        self.login_page.userLogin_valid(Globals.login_username, Globals.login_password)
        # more code ...
```

I removed my base Test Case which had the setUpClass, snippet below:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver = webdriver.Ie(Globals.IEdriver_path)
    cls.driver.get(Globals.URL_riaz_pc)
    cls.login_page = login.LoginPage(cls.driver)
```

I moved the code to browse to the URL login_page from setUpClass to the init method in the AdministrationPage Test Case.

Is my setup not correct?  How can i fix this so it opens only 1 instance of the browser and run the test cases?

------------ My revised test suite code and AdministrationPage_TestCase -----

Test Suite:

```
class Test_Suite(unittest.TestCase):

suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestCases.AdministrationPage_TestCase.AdministrationPage_TestCase))
suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(TestCases.DataMapsPage_TestCase.DatamapsPage_TestCase))
dateTimeStamp = time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M_%S')
buf = file(r"C:\\Webdriver\\ClearCore\\TestReport\\\TestReport_" + get_datetime_now() + ".html", "wb")
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(
        stream=buf,
        title='Test the Report',
        description='Result of tests'
        )
runner.run(suite)
```

AdministrationPage_TestCase

```
from selenose.cases import SeleniumTestCase

class AdministrationPage_TestCase(SeleniumTestCase):

project_name_from_file = "" 

def test_a1_browse_to_url_and_login(self):
#def __init__(self):
    self.driver.get(Globals.URL_riaz_pc)
    self.login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(120)
    self.driver.maximize_window()

def test_a2_add_Project(self):
    print "*** test_add_project ***"
    project_name = Globals.project_name_regression + get_datetime_now()
    print "project_name_value = " + project_name
    write_project_Name_toFile2(project_name)
    AdministrationPage_TestCase.project_name_from_file = project_name
    self.login_page.userLogin_valid(Globals.login_username, Globals.login_password)
    menu_bar = MenuBarPage(self.driver)
    administration_page = menu_bar.select_menuBar_item("Administration")
    administration_page.click_add_project_button()
    time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: It seems that `suiteClass()` instance should be called without any arguments, but in your case there is an argument `(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))`

Comment: I have correct my TestSuite now.  The test suite starts to run and the browser opens and navigates to the URL, logins and just sits there for some time.  The test then exits.  In the Python Console it says Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.

Comment: Could it be it is not reading the browser instance from the nose setup config file?